# What is the value of side $AC$ in the triangle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

For reference:The angle B of a triangle ABC measures 60°. The AN and CM medians are plotted. The radius of the circle inscribed in the MBNG quadrilateral
(G is centroid(barycenter) of ABC) measures $\sqrt3$ . Calculate AC.

My progress
[image]

$\triangle BED: \\sen30 = \frac{\sqrt3}{BD}\therefore BD = 2\sqrt3\\
cos 30 = \frac{BE}{BD}\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{BE}{2\sqrt3}\therefore BE = 3\implies BN = 3+\sqrt3\\
\triangle BNG:cos 30 = \frac{BN}{BG}\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{3+\sqrt3}{BG}\rightarrow BG = \frac{6+2\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}=2\sqrt3+2\\
BG = \frac{2BP}{3}\rightarrow BP = 3\sqrt3 + 3\\
\triangle BPC: tg30 = \frac{PC}{BP}\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt3}{3} = \frac{PC}{3\sqrt3+3} \implies \boxed{ PC = 3+\sqrt3}\\
\therefore \boxed{\color{red}AC = 2(3+\sqrt3) = 6+2\sqrt3}$

My question...only the equilateral triangle meets the conditions? Why if the quadrilateral is indescribable $\measuredangle MGN=120^o$

Comment: I assume the second question you have is why does $BMGN$ cyclic imply $\angle MGN=120$. This is because opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral sum to 180 degrees.

Comment: Is $\angle PBC = 30^\circ$ given by the question? I see that $AN$ and $CM$ are medians, so $G$ is the centroid, so $BP$ may not be the angle bisector of $\angle B = 60^\circ$. Or rather, the incentre $D$ of quadrilateral $MBNG$ may be outside median $BP$.

Comment: Your progress assumes a lot that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral (how median $BP$ is also an angle bisector, how medians $AN$ and $BP$ are also altitudes). Is that given?

Comment: @peterwhy...no..only reference data was provided, ($B = 60^o)$  The drawing was not provided either, so my question

Comment: @TheBestMagician...exactly

Comment: @peterwhy.,,In the inscribable quadrangle, the bisectors pass through the center

Comment: @petaarantes Yes about the angle bisectors, so I was questioning if $BDG$ is a straight line.

Comment: @peterwhy...the correct term would be centroid in English and not centroid as I had posted .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129410/discussion-between-peta-arantes-and-peterwhy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Given $ \small MBNG$ is a tangential quadrilateral, it is easy to see that,

$ \small BN + MG = BM + GN$

[How? $ \small BE + EN = BF + NH, MK + KG = MF + GH$. In fact there is a theorem called Pitot Theorem that states the same.]

So if $ \small AN = d, CM = e$, we have $ \small MG = \frac{e}{3}, \small GN = \frac{d}{3}$ and we rewrite $\small BN + MG = BM + GN$ as,

$\frac{c}{2} + \frac{d}{3} = \frac{a}{2} + \frac{e}{3}$

$ d + \frac{3c}{2} = e + \frac{3a}{2} \tag1$

Now given the circle is also the incircle of $\triangle BCM$ and $\triangle ABN$, AND the area of both $\triangle ABN$ and $\triangle BCM$ are same, which is half the area of $\triangle ABC$, we conclude they must have the same perimeter.

$c + d + \frac{a}{2} = a + e + \frac{c}{2}$

$d + \frac{c}{2} = e + \frac{a}{2} \tag2$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, $c = a$.

As $a = c ~$ and angle between the sides is $60^\circ$, $\triangle ABC$ must be an equilateral triangle.

So we easily find that,

$ \small AC = BC = 2 BN = 2 (BE + EN) =  2 (3 + \sqrt3)$

Answer (score 2):

Since $BNGM$ has an inscribed circle, it must follow pitot theorem i.e. the opposite sides must sum to the same value. Let $x,y,d$ be the lengths of $BM, BN, BG$ respectively.

By law of cosines, we have
$$MG=\sqrt{x^2+d^2-xd\sqrt{3}}$$
$$NG=\sqrt{y^2+d^2-yd\sqrt{3}}$$
By pitot theorem,
$$x+\sqrt{y^2+d^2-yd\sqrt{3}}=y+\sqrt{x^2+d^2-xd\sqrt{3}}$$
$$x-\sqrt{x^2+d^2-xd\sqrt{3}}=y-\sqrt{y^2+d^2-yd\sqrt{3}}$$
Consider the function $f(x)=x-\sqrt{x^2+a^2-xa\sqrt{3}}$ for some real parameter $a$. We have that
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{2x-a\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{x^2+a^2-xa\sqrt{3}}}$$
If $u=\frac{x}{a}$, this is equivalent to
$$1-\frac{2u-\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{u^2-u\sqrt{3}+1}}$$
$$=1-\sqrt{\frac{4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}u+3}{4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}+4}}$$
$$=1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}+4}}$$
Since $u\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}+4\in [1,\infty)$, which implies
$$\frac{1}{4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}+4}\in (0,1]$$
$$\implies 1-\frac{1}{4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}+4}\in [0,1)$$
$$\implies \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}+4}}\in [0,1)$$
$$\implies 1-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4u^2-4u\sqrt{3}+4}}\in (0,1]$$
Hence, $f'(x)$ is positive$~\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, which means $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.

This means that the only solution to
$$f(x)=f(y)$$
is when $x=y$. So $BM=BN$. From there it follows that the original triangle is equilateral. The rest of the answer follows.

Answer (score 2):

Since $$BM+GN=BN+MG,$$ in the standard notation we obtain:
$$\frac{c}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}$$ or
$$3(a-c)+\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}-\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}=0$$ or
$$(a-c)\left(1+\frac{a+c}{\sqrt{2a^2+2b^2-c^2}+\sqrt{2b^2+2c^2-a^2}}\right)=0,$$ which gives $a=c$ and our triangle is an equilateral triangle.

Thus, $$AC=2BN=2(EN+BE)=2(\sqrt3+3).$$